# Small office network labeling

Tags: networking, visio

I'm looking for advice on labeling a small network . There are 24 workstations at my office. I've labeled switches like "SW01". Also i've labeled the tables with the workstations on. 
For example : 
Table number 1 computer that connects to switch number 1 looks like SW01-1(at each end of cables). Now I want to document the labeling in Visio
I need a good solution to label. How do you label ? Also how to I draw labels in Visio?

Answer (score 4):

In general: don't name or label computers after the switches or switch ports they are connected to - this usually changes far too often for labeling to keep pace with and creates a lot of confusion once it doesn't match the physical situation anymore (What? SW01-5 is connected to Port 5 of SW03?). There is also a lot of naming ambiguity by using the switch name as the starting part of the computer name. Give independent names to your computers (like PC123), label the switches and the cables if you need to know the exact port assignments and document them.

If you are documenting in Visio, it would be a good idea to place the connection information within the shape's attributes and expose them on the drawing as necessary using Visio's "data graphics" feature.

Comment: Labeling each end of the cable with both pieces of kit it plugs into is a good idea, as long as you relabel the cable as soon as anything changes...

Comment: SW01-5 mean the PC on the table number 5 is connected switch number 1. I'm asking that is it good solution for label?

Comment: Probably not as much as you would expect. An installed cable will (if it is part of a structured cabling) usually not interconnect PCs and switches, but wall outlets and patch panels. You would need find a naming schema that is a) easy to read and understand, b) does have as few dependencies on varying circumstances as possible (i.e. is going to last). Your table arrangement and switch numbers might change, your cable runs probably will not.